# Custom knockout handler for bootstrap typeahead not working with Firefox 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I have the next problem: I am using bootstrap and knockout and I have a custom method for typeheads:

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.typeahead = {
update : function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    $(element).typeahead({
        source : typeaheadSource[$(element).attr('id')]
    });
    var span = $(element.parentElement).children("span");
    if (span.length > 0) {
        span[0].onclick = function() {
            var t = typeaheadByElementId[$(element).attr('id')];
            if (t.shown == false) {
                hideAllTypeaheads();
                t.showAll();
            } else {
                t.hide();
            }
        };
    }
}
};
```

A part of the typeheadSource array

```
var typeaheadSource = [];
...
typeaheadSource['buildingWalls'] = [ 'blah', 'ablah', 'cblah-blah'];
...
```

And an html code for typeahead inputs:

```
 <div class='control-group'><label class='control-label' for='buildingWalls'>Материал наружных стен</label>
            <div class='input-append'>
                <input type='text' class='input-xlarge' id='buildingWalls' data-bind='value:buildingWalls, typeahead: true'> <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-chevron-down"></i></span>
            </div>
 </div>
```

It works normally on firefox 18 and chrome both, BUT it doesn't work on Firefox 5 (for example). About what i want to get: all the tips should be shown to you after you click on the span

Comment: Could you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-       var span = $(element.parentElement).children("span");
-       if (span.length > 0) {
-           span[0].onclick = function() {

+       var span = element.nextElementSibling;
+       if (span) {
+           span.onclick = function() {
```

$(element.parentElement).children("span") returns empty array in Firefox 5, so I've replaced this 3 lines with new ones.